# Moving list workflow from development to production

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I created a 2010 workflow in SPD 2013 on development machine. Once it was time to go live, I took site collection back up from development and restored it on production so my workflow as well as all InfoPath 2013 forms were moved.

Now I have made several changes in workflow as well as forms on development machine. What is the best way to move both workflow and forms to production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For workflow - you can use import export feature of workflow assuming you don't have direct reference of your development url anywhere. 
For Infopath forms -  you need to do manual changes.

Consider this as limitation but best way is to do it manually...mark all changes you are doing in dev environment and move all changes manually to production.

Answer (score 0):

1. SharePoint Designer 2013 provides the facility to save the workflow as a template, it saves to the Site Assets as .WSP file
2. Then you can export is as .WSP, which can be imported to any other site collection goto Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Under Galleries click on Solution gallery, after uploaded .wsp file click on "Activate solution" to activate it.
3. Goto Site Settings of that site and click on "Manage Features" now simply activate the workflow to use it in the Site.

SharePoint designer 2013, provides the facility to export all the three types of workflows Site Workflows, List Workflows and Re-usable workflows.

More information please see the below link.

http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/05/move-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow.html